# Footer out of place

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I know that there are probably a million posts here about footers that are out of place. I already read them and went through all those sugestions and tried them!

**Didn't work!**

I wonder if that is because I have a PHP footer... I don't know if that makes any difference or not! Anyway, here goes the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>bla bla</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("template_top.php"); ?>
<div id="pagecorpo">

contents  

</div>
<?php include_once("template_down.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for my "template_down.php":

```
<div id="pagedown">

<span><a href="#">Om porjektet</a></span>
- <span><a href="#">Hjälp</a></span>
- <span><a href="#">Kontakter</a></span>
- <span><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></span>
</div>
<div id="pagedown2">Brand of the website :: 2013</div>
```

And here it comes the CSS:

```
body {
    width:1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#282828;
}

a img {
    border:none;
}

#pagecorpo {
    height:420px;
}

#pagedown {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#87b640;
    height:20px;
}

#pagedown2 {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:20px;
}
```

**NOTE:** I know I should have #pagecorpo with 100% height but I already tried it, as well as a footer wraper with a "clear:both;" and it really didn't work. This is therefore the original code.

The page has javascript contents that loads dynamic content (changes size according with the user's interaction). I want the footer allways stays at the bottom...

So, what to do?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you have an `</div>` for `#pagedown`

Comment: @AaronGoff, yes it does. After the last `</span>`.

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to say without knowing 1) what you consider "out of place" to be 2) what the CSS associated with the HTML is.

Comment: @AaronGoff He does. His `spans` are inside it.

Comment: Define "out of place".

Comment: Try `<div id="pagedown"><?php include_once("template_down.php"); ?> (PHP file's content)</div>`. I had a similar problem before and did that, which worked for me.

Comment: Edit your question to include your `style.css` stylesheet. Might help to shed a bit of light on the subject. ;)

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Only the rendered HTML and CSS are of any concern.

Comment: Ok, we have all the parts, now define `out of place`. What is the problem? We can't all copy your code and test something we're not entirely sure "what" to look for. So, define "out of place".

Comment: I added the CSS and out of place means no matter what I do to the CSS it allways stays in the middle of the page or right after the <?php include_once("template_top.php"); ?>

Comment: @OP: Does this Fiddle match what you are seeing?: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpp7M/

Comment: So, how do you want it to be positioned? Is "it", the footer?

Comment: No... Unless the container #pagecorpo has a fixed height in px, the footer comes allways in the middle of the page (in the front of the contents) or right after the "<?php include_once("template_top.php"); ?>". And I need a PHP footer because the site is huge and if/when I need to change something on the footer I cannot change it in literaly hundreds of files...

Comment: Fred, I want my footer to be allways at the bottom of the page, as it should be, no matter how big the container #pagecorpo is...

Comment: If you want your footer to be center-aligned, use `<div id="pagedown" align="center">`, if that's what you're looking for. I tried Seth's Fiddle and used my above said code and it centered it perfectly.

Comment: "Always be at the bottom", meaning "always visible/fixed"?

Comment: Center?? No, I didn't say center, I said bottom :( I have no problem in centering the footer...

Comment: Fred, I have contents being loaded with Javascript. This means that the size of the page is bigger or smaller, depending on the clicks that the user does. So, the footer has to be allways at the bottom of the page, no matter how long the page is...

Comment: You could use something along the line of: `position:absolute /* or fixed */; bottom:0; left:0;  width:100%;  margin: 0,auto;` if that answers your question. Other than that, am at a loss.

Comment: @user2104321 You're welcome. Keep me posted. Added note: Consider including your "Brand of the website :: 2013" inside the same div, then just `span` it for styling.